# How do I handle a scenario to upload huge csv file of 50,000 records in SAP FIM application using VuGen?

Tags: loadrunner

I am working with "SAP BusinessObjects Financial Information Management" application where I have a scenario to upload a CSV File.

Uploading of CSV file would take 2 hours as the size of the csv file is huge.

In VuGen while recording should i wait till the file gets uploaded or is there any work around for this.

How do i handle this in Load Generator?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add a loop to the script which checks every 1 if the file load is complete.
I'll also have the file load in a seperate script and have all other activity or performance testing processes in other scripts.

This way you isolate the response time on an 2hour file upload and quicker response times, the file upload will also create nice load on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest workaround is to upload a smaller file and then replace this file in the actual test with the large file.

**Just as a note**

What perplexes me is how long it takes to upload the file. Performance testing should be done close to the servers or SAP machines in this case. A local LAN of 1 GB should upload even the largest CSV files in seconds.. unless of course SAP is the bottleneck, and again it would be pointless to performance test something that is slow already ..

Also if you are uploading from a remote location behind a slow modem or something like this it is also pointless to do performance testing from there.